# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

[image: ipython code]
i'm trying to generate seed using TensorFlow 2.1 but this error appears  **module 'TensorFlow' has no attribute 'random'**

Comment: run this command and try ```pip install --upgrade tensorflow```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you think you're using TensorFlow 2.0 but actually, it is a previous version of tensorflow.

It's easy to check:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

This should produce output like this:

```
2.1.0
```

If not, you know you have the wrong TensorFlow version installed.

---

It's also possible that you have multiple versions of python installed. For example:

- Python 3.6 might be installed with TensorFlow 1.x, and
- Python 3.7 might be installed with TensorFlow 2.x.

In this case, just be careful that the version of Python being used by Jupyter Notebook is the version of Python with TensorFlow 2.x installed.

Comment: it worked when I downgraded TensorFlow version to 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

just want to make sure

run this command then restart the runtime `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`
and then try that code again