# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random' for tensorflow version 1.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow version 1.3.0
Cuda version 8
and cuDNN version 6

When I run `python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"` I see the below error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random'
```

Please help me as I am stuck on this for quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow 1.3 uses [`tf.random_normal`](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.3/site/en/api_docs/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal.md) and not `tf.random.normal`.

You'll find the TensorFlow 1.3 [documentation on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.3/site/en/api_docs/api_docs/python/tf)

---

**Note:** I suggest you do not use tf 1.3 unless explicitly required : tf1 does not receive any updates anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your tensorflow version

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Also, check [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575143/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-random).